# Using OpenAI LLMs for classification. Asking for classification vs. asking for probabilities

Tags: text-classification, openai-api, multilabel-classification, gpt-4, large-language-model

I'm using LLMs for classifying products into specific categories. Multi-Class.

1. One way to do it would it to ask if it's a yes/no for a specific category and loop through the categories.
2. Another way would be to ask for a probability that that certain product belongs to one of those classes.

The second option allows me to adjust the prediction thresholds in "post" and over/under-classify certain classes.

However, The word on the street is that RLHF-trained OpenAI models such as `gpt-3.5-turbo` and `gpt-4` are weak at guessing probabilities relative to text completion models like `text-davinci-003` because RLHF training makes the model "think" more like a human (bad at guessing probabilities).

Are there any literature I can read up on/ should know about? Before I go ahead and run a 100 tests.

I've not tried anything as of yet given that testing is time/cost intensive. And would like a baseline understanding of how to tackle the problem before starting.

Comment: Can you share a block of text and the categories for the products you are looking to classify into?